# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, permission-denied

I want to create an user that can access from any hosts to Mysql server

I use

`create user abc@10.10.131.17 identified by 'abc123'`

and

`grant all privileges mydb.* to 'abc'@'%';`

But when i run client,the error occurs: 
`"java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'abc'@'10.10.0.7' (using password: YES)`

help me,please!

Comment: You have created a user with 10.10.131.17 IP and you are trying to connect MySQL Server from 10.10.10.7. It won't work. For that you have to create user with 10.10.10.7 IP `create user abc@10.10.10.7 identified by 'abc123'`

Comment: I used VPN for actual LAN, and i want to access from any where ,i have created a user 'abc'@'%'. but it did not work. i afraid that when i am in other network,may it be fine?

Comment: Check my answer and create a user allowing all IPs. And check your server has any firewall running. Allow these IPs in firewall on server

Comment: Firewall would not be the issue, since he gets a clear MySQL error in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious guess would be that you didn't do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after issuing `GRANT` statement.

Another obvious guess (not sure if typo in the question) is that syntax of `GRANT` is `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'abc'@'%';`, with `ON` in it.

Comment: sorry for typing wrong,
i used"flush privileges" after grant command with ON as you say

Answer (score 0):

You have created an user with allowing IP `10.10.131.17` and you are trying to connect MySQL Server from IP `10.10.10.7`. So it won't work. 
To access MySQL Server you have to create user allowing IP `10.10.10.7` or allowing all IPs using `%`.

```
CREATE USER `abc`@`10.10.10.7` IDENTIFIED BY 'abc123' 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES mydb.* TO `abc`@`10.10.10.7`;
```

**OR**

```
CREATE USER `abc`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY 'abc123' 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES mydb.* TO `abc`@`%`;
```

Comment: yes, It is fine at the first case
I also tried the second case,but it does not work, Thanks

Comment: Have you checked my comment on your question