# Unable to access RDS database from EC2 instance webapp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

First of all, we are able to access the RDS/MySQL database using the following command:

```
mysql -h ckinstance.cx2ecc4osrgp.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u ck -p<PASSWORD>
```

We then tried adding in the root user and password to provide access to the RDS/MySQL database via:

```
create user 'ck'@'ckinstance.cx2ecc4osrgp.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' identified by '<PASSWORD>';
grant all privileges ck.* to 'ck'@'ckinstance.cx2ecc4osrgp.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com';
```

Our webapp properties file has:

```
com.careerkick.jpa.url=jdbc:mysql://ckinstance.cx2ecc4osrgp.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/ck
com.careerkick.jpa.username=ck
com.careerkick.jpa.password=<password>
```

However, when we run our webapp, the logs show that it's still trying to access it via the localhost:

```
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - 
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@6c3bae8 -- Acquisition 

Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new 
resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition
attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'ck'@'172.31.29.230' (using password:   YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1709)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1252)
```

For some reason, it seems to want to use the localhost IP.

I also tried creating the user via using a localhost IP as well.

create user 'ck'@'172.31.29.230' identified by '';

But that didn't work either.

I also used this article as a reference:

[java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058486/java-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user)

Are there any other suggestions or is there something else I might be missing in regards to this database connection issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you grant access on RDS, you grant access to the host you are connecting from, not the host you are connecting to. Being that private IPs usually change within ec2, its best to use the security group to control access and set grants with a wildcard host `%`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will try the wildcard host setting.