# Hibernate database connection auto qualifying username incorrectly

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm having an issue with hibernate wanting to add on an @.myisp.whatever.net onto the end of the username. Even if I try to qualify it myself with @mydatabase.com it will still tack on another @ how do I stop it from doing that?

Hibernate Config:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://mydatabase.com:3306/database</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username@mydatabase.com</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Error:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username@mydatabase.com'@'111-111-111-111.slkc.qwest.net' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: This error message comes from the database itself, not from Hibernate. You're trying to connect from 111-111-111-111.slkc.qwest.net, and the database refuses the connection.

Comment: Yes but the database allows connections from any ip address with that username. Why would I have to create a new user every single time I change ip addresses?

Comment: AFAIK, you don't have to. Simply pass username, and not username@mydatabase.com. MySQL knows from where you're trying to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give access to user no?

```
CREATE USER `username`@`111-111-111-111.slkc.qwest.net` IDENTIFIED BY 'username' 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES mydb.* TO `username`@`111-111-111-111.slkc.qwest.net`;
```

maybe this can help you
[java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058486/java-sql-sqlexception-access-denied-for-user)

Comment: Should I have to add a new stinking user for every IP address I connect from? That sounds like it can't be right.

Comment: no, no just from every IP. just give privileges to user to remote access

Comment: Ah I see your link now, that makes sense, will attempt that and report back.